# Recording Audio Using DFSDM on an STM microcontroller

Tags: c, audio, embedded, stm32

On the STM32L4 Discovery kit for IoT node (`B-L47E-IOT0A1`), there are two `MP34DT01` microphones: one
with LR pulled to VDD and the second with LR pulled low. `DFSDM1_CKOUT` and
`DFSDM1_DATIN2` are connected for both. I have this board, with the system clock set at 80MHz, and `DFSDM CH2` enabled In `DMA` mode. Additionally I have the filter set in continuous mode with `Fosr` set at 52, and `Iosr` at 8. I can get values so I know that the microphones are working, but trying to play back the audio results in a bunch of static. I believe my sampling rate should be 48KHz because the interal SPI clock divider is set to 4. -- `(80MHz/4)/(52 * 8) = 48KHz]` --  My setup is below:

```
// Audio.c
#define AUDIO_LEN 240
#define H_AUDIO_LEN 120

int32_t micRecBuf[AUDIO_LEN];
int32_t micAudioBuf[AUDIO_LEN];
volatile uint8_t audioFilterHalfCplt = 0;
volatile uint8_t audioFilterCplt = 0;

void HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegConvHalfCpltCallback(DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef *hdfsdm_filter) {
    audioFilterHalfCplt = 1;
}
void HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegConvCpltCallback(DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef *hdfsdm_filter) {
     audioFilterCplt = 1;
 }

void micInit(DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef *hdfsdm_filter) {
    HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegularStart_DMA(hdfsdm_filter, micRecBuf, AUDIO_LEN);
}
```

```
while(true) {
   // first half of DMA is filled, now process
    if (audioFilterHalfCplt == 1) {
      // fill the audio buffer
      for (i = 0; i < H_AUDIO_LEN; i++) {
        micAudioBuf[i] = micRecBuf[i] << 8; // remove meta data
      }
      // reset the flag
      audioFilterHalfCplt = 0;
    }
    // second half is filled, finish process
    if (audioFilterCplt == 1) {
      // fill the audio buffer
      for (i = H_AUDIO_LEN; i < AUDIO_LEN; i++) {
        micAudioBuf[i] = micRecBuf[i] << 8; // remove meta data
      }
}
```

I am able to retrieve the data and save it to a binary file using this shell command:

`screen -S audio -L -Logfile audio.bin /dev/ttyACM1 9600, cs8`

And I save the data as a wav file using this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import wave

with open("audio.bin", "rb") as input_file:
    data = input_file.read()
    with wave.open("output.wav", "wb") as output_file:
        output_file.setnchannels(1)  # Assuming mono
        output_file.setsampwidth(4)  # Assuming 16-bit samples (2 bytes)
        output_file.setframerate(48077)  # Set the sample rate
        output_file.writeframesraw(data)
```

When I play back the audio file it is all static. Where am I going wrong in this process?

Comment: You're outputting mono 16 bit which is _2_ bytes but you specify _4_? Also, bitrates are usually 44100 (pc audio) or 48000 (mp4 audio), so 48077 seems strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Caveat:* Not a complete solution, but some things to try ...

Although, it may be an issue with the wiring or DMA setup, etc. there are some things to check first to ensure your capture and transfer process is correct.

1. From my top comment:
   You're outputting mono 16 bit which is 2 bytes but you specify 4? Also, bitrates are usually 44100 (pc audio) or 48000 (mp4 audio), so 48077 seems strange to me.
2. Can you *verify* that your PC captures the data correctly? That is, the baud rate, etc. are correct. Are both the PC and STM32 set correctly?
3. Have the STM32 output a fixed string of known bytes at the beginning. (e.g.) `for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) buf[i] = i;` That fixed [and *verifiable*] pattern should start the `.bin` file. You can examine this with a hex editor.
4. If you set up your PC to output [through its speakers] a pure tone (e.g. sine wave) and record that, when you get the `.bin` back file on your PC, you should be able to plot the raw data and see the sine wave.
5. Can you guarantee that when your DMA completes, that it completely fills the buffer? Is there a function you can call to get the number of bytes *actually* transferred by the DMA? (e.g.) Could you get a completion that has *fewer* bytes than you requested?
6. Could you have a race condition between the DMA and your code? Is your buffering scheme good enough to prevent the DMA from doing output to first and second halves, but go so fast that it tries to fill the first buffer [partially] again?
7. In other words, your base waits for a "DMA complete" flag (e.g. `audioFilterHalfCplt`) and grabs the data. But, what prevents the DMA from writing the *next* chunk of data into that buffer *while* you are pulling it out in your loop?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've corrected the issues in part one and can now get some sound with a lot of static. I have verified #2. I'll look into the remaining possibilities.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because in the time it will take me to verify all of these things this question will become stale. I'll ask a new question after I've tried all of this if it's still not working. Thanks again.